# AttributeError: 'cv2.dnn.DetectionModel' object has no attribute 'setInput

Tags: python, opencv

MY Code is yolo object detetction. 
This is my code

[image]

This my error. please anyone answer to my problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It says that cv2.dnn.DetectionModel does not have the function setInput. According to the [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/df1/classcv_1_1dnn_1_1DetectionModel.html), cv2.dnn.DetectionModel inherits from [cv2.dnn.Model](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/df0/classcv_1_1dnn_1_1Model.html), which has no attribute "setInput". Try setting the input one by one. Perhaps you can refer from this [kaggle notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/chienhsianghung/object-detection-using-opencv-inference).